# Perl Mojolicious Render Large Text File

Tags: perl, mojolicious

I a large log file and want to open it with the browser using Mojolicious. My customers will click on the link and I want to read the file content from the server and return it to the user. I used the following trick to solve it:

```
my $res = `cat $file`;
if (! $res) {
    $self->render(text => "An error while trying to read the log file. \nPlease try to refresh the page.");
}
else {
    $self->render(text => $res);
}
```

Now - I have a large file and I always get an Out of Memory error when reading it.

How can I render large file content to the users?

I tried to solve it with:

```
$self->res->headers->content_type('text/plain');
$self->res->content->asset(Mojo::Asset::File->new(path => file));
$self->rendered(200);
```

it solves the issue but it takes a lot of time until it reads the file content and show the results in the browser.

How can show the file content to the users while the page still loading?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to investigate [chunked transfer encoding](https://mojolicious.org/perldoc/Mojolicious/Guides/Rendering#Chunked-transfer-encoding). Read the file in chunks and send those chunks to the client.